# How to pipe and loop over a list of directories in cmd and PowerShell?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell

Here's what I have to do:

1. get a list of cloned organizations using `es $tf` command
2. loop over them and for each:
3. cd into that directory, then use `tf status` to get the current status of the user
4. pipe this result into a C# Console application to check it

Here's what I have written, but it does not work:

```
es $tf | for %%i in stdin do "tf status | Check.dll"
```

How can I fix it. Also since PowerShell is the official new way to go in Windows, how can I have it in PowerShell?

**Update**

[es](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/) is the command line interface of VoidTool Everything (a superfast search tool for Windows)

[tf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands?view=azure-devops) is the command line interface to work with Azure DevOps TFVC.

Comment: [1] what is `es`? ///// [2] what is `tf`?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, thanks for mentioning that. Updated the question.

Comment: `es $tf | for %%i in stdin do "tf status | Check.dll"` this is a mix of cmd and bash commands and won't work in either, and obviously never works in powershell. Moreover `tf status | Check.dll` is very wrong unless `Check.dll` is really an executable file

Comment: You might want to read `about_For` and `about_ForEach` and `about_Pipelines` help articles for PowerShell.

Comment: @phuclv, that's why I asked.

Comment: @AHCloud - thank you for the clarification. [*grin*]

Comment: @AHCloud can you add sample output from `es $tf` - is it just file paths? I think in powershell it would simply look like `es.exe $tf | tf.exe status $_ | Check.dll` as long as the output is exactly right.